# AVPlayerLooper, AVComposition with AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters : volume is instable between loops

Tags: ios, avplayer, avmutablecomposition, avplayerlooper

I use a AVPlayerLooper to loop a video inside an AVPlayer.
The video is actually an AVComposition merging two audio tracks and one video track.

I apply two audiomix input parameters on the composition, one for each audio track to manage their respective volume (using setVolume() method).
Note also that one of the audio track has also a tap processor to apply some audio filters, using the dedicated property inside the audiomix input parameter.

Everything seems to work fine but I noticed an issue with the volume:

**The first loop is fine and render the expected volume, but the volume of the next loops seems to be random, one loop being at the expected volume (let’s say 4.0 in setVolume()), the other being at default (1.0).**

Note that if I mute and unmute the AVPlayer while playing in a loop where the volume is lower than expected, the volume comes back to its configured and expected value.

Note that exporting the same composition in a file (so out of any looper) with AVAssetExportSession is working great, the volume is always as expected.

**Have you got any tips to help me with this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything about this sounds like a bug (viz first loop works, `AVAssetExportSession` works), plus setting the volume of  `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters` to values outside of the documented [0, 1] range  sounds like the kind of thing that could provoke weird behaviour, HOWEVER changing the `MTAudioProcessingTap` creation flags from `kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects` to `kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PreEffects` seems to fix or at least work around this problem.

From the header file:

> `kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PreEffects`
>           Signifies that the processing tap is inserted before any effects.
>       `kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects`
>           Signifies that the processing tap is inserted after any effects.

My reading of this is that the two flags only change who gets first bite at the audio: the tap or the `AVAudioMix` `inputParameters` (`inputParameters` don't get special precedence flags so I assume they are applied in array order?). Nothing about all this suggests that mix configuration is thrown away at a certain point in time, so I guess pre-fx just happens to let you avoid the buggy, unhappy code path.

So in summary, I hope that it's not a problem for you to apply volume control *after* your tap. If it is, just apply the volume yourself inside your tap.

But, man, a nasty interaction between `AVPlayerLooper`, `AVComposition` and `MTAudioProcessingTap`? Yikes. And flags are always a red flag in API design.

Comment: Great! Changing form PostEffects to PreEffects « fixed » my issue. Thanks